# PHP convert double quoted string to single quoted string

Tags: php, unicode-string

I know this question asked here many times.But That solutions are not useful for me. I am facing this problem very badly today.

```
// Case 1
$str = 'Test \300';  // Single Quoted String
echo json_encode(utf8_encode($str)) // output: Test \\300

// Case 2
$str = "Test \300"; // Double Quoted String
echo json_encode(utf8_encode($str)) // output: Test \u00c0
```

I want case 2's output and I have single quoted $str variable. This variable is filled from XML string parsing . And that XML string is saved in txt file.

(Here \300 is encoding of À (latin Charactor) character and I can't control it.)

Please Don't give me solution for above static string

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do:

```
$string = '\300';

$string = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\\d{1,3}/', function (array $match) {
    return pack('C', octdec($match[0]));
}, $string);
```

It matches any sequence of a backslash followed by up to three numbers and converts that number from an octal number to a binary string. Which has the same result as what `"\300"` does.

Note that this will *not* work exactly the same for *escaped escapes*; i.e. `"\\300"` will result in a literal `\300` while the above code will convert it.

If you want *all* the possible rules of double quoted strings followed without reimplementing them by hand, your best bet is to simply `eval("return \"$string\"")`, but that has a number of caveats too.

Comment: Thanks you very much !! You are master !! Your first solution working for me , But eval("return \"$string\"") is not working for me. Thanks once again

Answer (score -3):

May You are looking for this

```
$str = 'Test \300';  // Single Quoted String
echo json_encode(stripslashes($str)); // output: Test \\300
```

Comment: I want output of case 2 but I have single quoted string (As in case 1) in $str variable. (Already I mentioned in my question)